# .scaledToFit OR .minimumScaleFactor on multiple Text

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to determine a mechanism to scale down an entire view to fit within a specific frame provided by the view that it is eventually integrated in.

My initial view I'm working with looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        Text("Example Text 1")
        CustomView()
        Text("Example Text 2")        
   }
}
```

I want this to scale down, both Text and the CustomView by the same amount to fit into the frame.  The CustomView already appropriately renders correctly when dimensions are given directly to it, aka CustomView().frame(width: XX, height: YY)

I first tried .scaleToFit().  This does indeed fit the view to the frame, but does so by truncating the text.  The size of the Text and CustomView are unchanged.

I next tried .minimumScaleFactor().  This also fits the view to the frame, but does so by resizing only the first Text.

I am looking for a method which will 1) scale both Text the same, 2) also scale the CustomView.  If I could somehow get the scale factor or scaled frame to hand to the CustomView it could be used to resize it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `.minimumScaleFactor` that seems to work fine for me.
You can also try with a combination of `GeometryReader` and `.scaleEffect`.

[image]

```
struct CustomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(.orange)
            .overlay(
                Text("CustomView")
            )
    }
}

struct ScaleSubview: View {
    
    @State private var width = 200.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack() {
                Text("Example Text 1")
                CustomView()
                Text("Example Text 2")
            }
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
            .frame(width: width, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            Slider(value: $width, in: 0...400)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```